# Can an Indian citizen visit Poland for a business trip under the current restrictions?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, covid-19, poland

I have an Indian passport with a 3 year Tier 2 visa from the UK, and a 2 year Schengen visa issued by France. My company has a meeting in Poland in September. I live in the UK and will not have travelled outside in the fourteen days prior to the trip. Am I allowed to visit under the current restrictions?

I checked with [Timatic](http://cms.olympicair.com/timatic/webdocsI/spdbmainv.html) and the [official government website](https://www.gov.pl/web/coronavirus/travel) which has conflicting information.

Timatic states:

> - Passengers are not allowed to enter.
>   This does not apply to passengers arriving from Austria,
>   Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Czechia, Denmark,
>   Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary,
>   Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein,
>   Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway,
>   Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden,
>   Switzerland or United Kingdom.

where I should be allowed as a passenger with a valid Schengen visa arriving from the UK. The official government website makes no such exemptions and only seems to allow non-EU nationals if they are spouses of Polish citizens, or have EU residence cards and are travelling to their homes, or have essential jobs.

Does that mean I'm not allowed to visit for a business trip?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.